# On clicking material-ui autocomplete blank page is opening in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, dropdown

When I click on Autocomplete component imported from material-ui it is showing blank page.

```
const defaultProps = {
     options: catalogs,
     getOptionLabel: (option) => option.catalogsLink,
   };
<Autocomplete
        {...defaultProps}
        id="debug"
        debug
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="catalog link" margin="normal" />}
      />
```

Answer (score 2):

Its showing you blank page on clicking because you are not passing options prop in Autocomplete component. options prop accepts an array of all options you want to show.

For example

```
const countries = [
 { code: 'AD', label: 'Andorra', phone: '376' },
 { code: 'AE', label: 'United Arab Emirates', phone: '971' },
 { code: 'AF', label: 'Afghanistan', phone: '93' },
 { code: 'AG', label: 'Antigua and Barbuda', phone: '1-268' },
 { code: 'AI', label: 'Anguilla', phone: '1-264' },
 { code: 'AL', label: 'Albania', phone: '355' },
 { code: 'AM', label: 'Armenia', phone: '374' },
];
```

now pass this countries array to options prop

```
options={countries}
```

for code visit [codesandbox.io/material-ui-demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xjr3b?file=/demo.js:819-838)